# How to insert text into a richtext textbox using VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access VBA, I have been trying to programmatically insert code into a form's richtext textbox control when the user presses a button.  The idea is to put a mark where the user's cursor is at the time the user presses the button--the mark will signify the start of text where the user enters a comment about the text.

However, presumably because the richtext textbox has hidden formatting codes embedded (e.g., <div>, etc.), using .SelStart and .SelLength does not seem to get me to the correct position in the textbox when I am trying to insert the new text.  It is consistently inserting the text earlier in the textbox than where the cursor was when the button is clicked, but not a consistent number of characters earlier.

Although I've done a search and found some wonderful functions for inserting text into a standard textbox (e.g., Lebans' InsertAtCursor function), I cannot get those functions to work for richtext textboxes either--that is, they have the same problem as code that I wrote myself; it inserts the new text too early in the existing textbox text.

Anyone have a solution for programmatically inserting new text into a richtext textbox at the cursor position?

Here is code (obviously, I could make the code more efficient, but I was just trying to get something working first) from one of my attempts.  It inserts text, but, not at the correct location, presumably due to the richtext formatting that does not visibly appear in the textbox but apparently influences .SelStart position values:

```
Dim intSelStart As Integer  'this is the starting location of the selection in the note at the time the comment was initially added
Dim strAddComment as String  'this is the string comment that I want to add--it is not the comment itself, it is a flag that will indicate the comment number

strAddComment = "|1`17|"  'the | characters delimit the comment flag; the first number is the comment number so 1 is the first comment, 2 is the second, etc.; the value after the ` is the length of the text selected in the textbox to which the comment applies, e.g., `17 means the comment applies to 17 selected characters

Forms!frmAppt_individual.SetFocus  'set the focus to the main form
Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.SetFocus  'set the focus to the subform so we can get the .Sel property values of the text selected in the textbox on the subform
Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.Form.Controls("Note").SetFocus  'set focus on the control which is required to get the .Sel property values
intSelStart = Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.Form.Controls("Note").SelStart

'now try to insert the comment
Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.Form.Controls("Note") = Left(Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.Form.Controls("Note"), intSelStart) & strAddComment & Mid(Forms!frmAppt_individual.sub_C.Form.Controls("Note"), intSelStart + 1)
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you show the code that isn't working that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You want a comment about data to be inserted into that data? Unfortunately, I don't think there is a solution because as you already recognized, the number of hidden richtext formatting characters already present cannot be known.

Comment: @LarsTech--thank you for the suggestion; however, I've tried multiple different coding attempts and I did note that using .SelStart and .SelLength in code does not work to insert data into the correct location.  I'll show some code, but I do not think it is due to an error in the existing code, I think it is that I need additional tools or ways to accomplish the goal given that it is a richtext textbox.

Comment: @June7--is there no way to detect the number of characters in the richtext box that are associated with richtext formatting characters and then adjust the location according to that?  Seems like there should be a way, but I certainly don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am posting code below that worked for me to insert text at the current insertion point into a richtext textbox using VBA code.  The use of the `PlainText` function seemed helpful.  Hopefully the code below will help someone else trying to do the same thing.

An explanation of the code:
The function fAddComment is contained in a standard module.  fAddComment is called when the user clicks a button btnAddComment on the parent form frmAppt.  A subform subNoteForm contains the richtext textbox named tbxNote.  The user is expected to have the insertion point at the position in the richtext textbox where the comment reference is inserted; the user may also have a number of characters selected that indicate the range of text to which the comment reference applies.  The function fAddComment will determine what comment number the new comment reference will be by counting any existing comment references already in the note.  The function will also count the number of characters selected when the comment reference is inserted so that a different function can later locate the comment reference and select the relevant characters.  The function adds, at the insertion point, a comment emoji (), followed by the comment reference number, followed by a ` character, followed by the number of characters selected when the comment reference was added, ending with a terminating comment emoji.  The function returns the string of the comment reference block that was added.

```
Public Function fAddComment() As String
    'this is used to add a new comment reference to the currently showing note
    'it returns "" if there is no note
    'it returns the string of the comment reference added to the note if a comment reference is successfully added
    
    Dim strBubble As String  'the comment bubble emoji string
    strBubble = ChrW(55357) & ChrW(56492)  'the comment bubble emoji

    Dim strProgNote As String
    Dim intMaxComment As Integer  'this is the maximum comment number found
    Dim intSelStart As Integer  'this is the starting location of the selection in the note at the time the comment was initially added
    Dim intSelLength As Integer  'this is the selection length in the note at the time the comment was initially added
    Dim whr As Integer  'this locates the next comment emoji and the emoji after it
    Dim intFoundValue As Integer  'this is the value of the found comment number
    Dim strNew As String  'the new string that holds the comment number and length
    Dim strSelectedText As String  'the text that is selected
    Dim intPosBeforeInsert As Integer  'the position of the insertion point prior to inserting the new comment reference
    
    'first, get the text of the progress note
    strProgNote = PlainText(Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote"))
    
    If Len(strProgNote) = 0 Then  'there's no note, so don't try to find comments
        fAddComment = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'get the selection length at the time the comment was initially added
    Forms!frmAppt.SetFocus  'set the focus to the main form
    Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.SetFocus  'set the focus to the subform so we can get the length of the text selected in the textbox on the subform
    Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SetFocus  'set focus on the control which is required to get the SelLength property
    intSelStart = Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelStart
    intSelLength = Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelLength
    strSelectedText = PlainText(Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelText)
    
    'now, find each comment emoji string and get the value
    intMaxComment = 0  'default to no comments
    
    whr = 1
    Do Until whr = 0
        whr = InStr(whr, strProgNote, strBubble)
        If whr > 0 Then  'found a comment, check the number
            intFoundValue = Val(Mid(strProgNote, whr + 2))  'the comment emoji consists of 2 characters, not just 1 character
            If intFoundValue > intMaxComment Then intMaxComment = intFoundValue  'the new value is greater so make it the highest value now
            whr = InStr(whr + 2, strProgNote, strBubble) + 2
        End If
    Loop
    
    'return the next comment number and the length of the selected string in the note
    strNew = strBubble & Trim(str(intMaxComment + 1)) & "`" & Trim(str(intSelLength)) & strBubble
    
    'insert the new comment reference into the note
    intPosBeforeInsert = Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelStart
    Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelLength = 0  'collapse selection
    Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelText = strNew  'insert the new comment text
    
    'move the insertion point back to the original location and after the comment reference we just added
    Forms!frmAppt.subNoteForm.Form.Controls("tbxNote").SelStart = intPosBeforeInsert + Len(strNew)
    
    fAddComment = strNew  'return the comment string we just added to the note
End Function
```